# Admin permissions for Jira users (Core and Confluence)

Tags: menu, permissions, jira, admin, confluence

We're running Jira 7.7.0 and Confluence 6.0.4

Our team is split into 2nd level support and 3rd level (us).

PROBLEM:
We would like to let 2nd level to do as much admin support as possible with as few permissions as needed.
1. The software offers for Core two admin groups, but both offer too many admin rights (Jira Administrators / Jira System Administrators)
2. Confluence has 2 groups Admins and users

DETAIL:
None of the global permissions of either permit, that we allow a group to 
- Add Spaces
- Add projects
- Add users
- Add groups
but keep them otherwise out of all the rest

DESIRED
A way to have a super user be able to not just manage >existing<, but also add the entities mentioned above.

OPTIONS?
A) A plugin that enhances users to be "a bit" Administrator, BUT with ADDING feature (this does not seem to exists)
B) A plugin that hides the menu items, but would technically still enable the users to execute the tasks if a URL was known

QUESTION
- Does anyone have a hint on what plugin could manage this? Either permission or menu hiding?
- Is there a way to trick configuration to achieve this (I assume not)

Many thanks!

Carsten

Answer (score 0):

There is an addon called [Delegated Project Creator for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211157/delegated-project-creator-for-jira) that address your request. To get it, search for it in the marketplace under "administration".

On the other hand you can tweak the UI of both apps to control access to options using Jquery. The addon [Script Runner for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/6820/scriptrunner-for-jira) has some options for this.